# Reproducir un vídeo en una ventana modal después de llamarlo desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, modal, dom, innerhtml, videojs

Hola tengo un dilema y es que he creado una forma de abrir una ventana modal y dentro un contenido en si "dinámico" desde mi .js.

La idea era que en momento de hacer click a un enlace (`<a>`) se abra la ventana modal con un 'titulo', 'video.mp4' y una 'sinopsis' según el enlace que haya clickeado.

Entonces he credo una clase de base de datos en mi .js donde tengo ese contenido y lo llamo en mi .html; el problema es que al momento de abrir solo el primer enlace, carga bien al principio: muestra la imagen del vídeo, el párrafo y el título, pero el botón de reproducir no funciona, y para que reproduzca tendría que usar el atributo autoplay de la etiqueta vídeo para que los botones funcionen. Pero al momento de pausar no se pueden volver a reproducir y aun así la barra de progreso y de volumen funcionan.

El otro problema es que solo el primer enlace abre la ventana modal con su contenido respectivo, pero los demás enlaces no abren la ventana modal. Sin embargo en la consola dice que cambió el contenido.

No sé si es un conflicto entre tanto código que he usado o todavía no es posible hacer lo que quiero hacer con esas herramientas o simplemente debo usar una ventana modal para cada vídeo y eso es mucho código que es lo que quiero evitar.

- editado *
  Logré arreglar el modal, lo que hice fue eliminar tanto las ids de los botones como los selectores de las mismas en javascript y abrir el modal con una función independiente la cual llamo desde onclick según su valor, por fin logré usar un solo modal para varios contenidos (bueno por ahora solo 2), conseguí usar el metodo dispose para limpiar el mismo espacio que van a usar diferentes videos a medida que voy cambiando, ahora mi otro problema es que aun siguen sin funcionar el botón de reproducir, solo se reproduce  si antes le doy el atributo autoplay a la etiqueta video (la cual hace que funcione el boton pero solo para pausar el video y la barra de volumen y de navegación del video) pero no me da opción de reproducir después de pausar, me pasee por la documentación de VideoJS en donde conseguí el método dispose , y no encontré mucho sobre como llamar una fuente desde la api, voy a seguir investigando. voy a actualizar el codigo para que lo vean de vista previa.

```js
/* cree un tipo de base de datos con una clase en javascript para llevar el contenido a la ventana modal de mi html */
    /* selecciono las etiquetas donde voy a insertar el contenido*/
        var ContenedorTitulo = document.querySelector('h2');
        var ContenedorMp4 = document.querySelector('video');
        var ContenedorSinopsis = document.querySelector('p');
    /* creo los criterios para las clases de contenido */
        function Contenido(titulo, mp4, sinopsis) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
            this.mp4 = mp4;
            this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
    /* aqui plasmo el contenido a los elementos de la ventana modal */
            this.plasmar = function () {
                ContenedorTitulo.innerHTML = titulo;
                ContenedorMp4.setAttribute('src', mp4);
                ContenedorSinopsis.innerHTML = sinopsis;
            };
        };
        /* creo las clases de contenido*/

        var contenido1 = new Contenido('Titulo del video 1', 'video1.mp4', 'descripcion del video 1');

        var contenido2 = new Contenido('Titulo del video 2', 'video2.mp4', 'descripcion del video 2');

/* eliminé el selector que abria el modal y su funcion junto con las ids de las etiquetas html y dejé los necesarios para la funcion independiente del modal */

let video = document.getElementById('fm-video');
let modal = document.getElementById('miModal');
let flex = document.getElementById('flex');
let cerrar = document.getElementById('close');

/* creé la funcion para abrir el modal llamandolo desde onClick segun el valor , tiene un efecto de fadeIn con css */

function abrir() {
    modal.classList.remove('modalOut');
    modal.classList.add('modalIn');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
};

/* con esto abro el modal segun el valor que le dí a mi funcion en onClick imprimiendo el contenido respectivo */

function caja(cont) {
    if(cont =="cont1") {
        contenido1.plasmar();
        ContenedorMp4.load();
        abrir();
    }
    else if(cont =="cont2") {
        contenido2.plasmar();
        ContenedorMp4.load();
        abrir();
    }
    else {};
}; 

/* seleccione la etiqueta a la cual voy a lmpiar el reproductor con dispose */

let contModal = document.querySelector('contenido-modal');

/* con esto cierro el modal con un efecto de fadeOut con css, cerraba muy rapido antes de dejar pasar la animacion con css entonces le dije que lo hiciera despues que terminace con setTimeout, al cerrar limpia el espacio de reproduccion con dispose */

cerrar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.remove('modalIn');
    modal.classList.add('modalOut');
    setTimeout(() => {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }, 800);
    video.pause();
    contModal.player.dispose();
});

/* igual que cerrar el modal solo que lo hace al hacer click fuera del contenido */

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if(e.target == flex){
    modal.classList.remove('modalIn');
    modal.classList.add('modalOut');
    setTimeout(() => {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }, 800);
    video.pause();
    contModal.player.dispose();
   }
});

/* con la libreria de VideoJs me veo obligado a usarlo porque sin el no reproduce los videos */

videojs('fm-video', {
    fluid: true
});
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: radial-gradient(center, circle, #dedede 0%, #3b3b3b 150%);
            background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle, #dedede 0%, #3b3b3b 100%);
            background: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle, #dedede 0%, #3b3b3b 100%);
            background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle, #dedede 0%, #3b3b3b 100%);
        }
    /* estos son los estilos de los botones tienen animacion */
        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 300;
            width: 190px;
            margin: 1em 0 1em 4.5%;
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            transition: box-shadow 1s;
        }

        .box:hover {
            box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 0px 10px;
        }

        /* Ventana Modal */

        .modal {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 4;
            overflow: auto;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
        }

        .modalIn {
            animation: In;
            animation-duration: 2s;
        }

        .modalOut {
            animation: Out;
            animation-duration: 1s;
        }
            
            @keyframes In {
          from {
            opacity: 0;
          }

          to {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }

        @keyframes Out {
          from {
            opacity: 1;
          }

          to {
            opacity: 0;
          }
        }

        .flex {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }    

        .contenido-modal {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            width: 60%;
            box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
            border-radius: 11px;
        }

        .modal-header {
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            font: bold 16px RobotoM;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            background: #747686;
        }
    /* esto lo puse para evitar que hagan clcic derecho al video */
        video {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .modal-body {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        p {
            font: bold 18px alegreya;
            text-align: justify;
            color: #464040;
        }

        p::first-letter {
           font: bold 30px alegreya;
        }

        .close {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 30px;
            transition: color 0.2s;
        }

        .close:hover {
            color: #ff0b0b;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.2/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.2/video.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    <!-- los botones, les borré la id que tenian y ahora solo uso el onclick -->
        <div class="box" onclick="caja('cont1')" href="#">boton 1</div>

        <div class="box" onclick="caja('cont2')" href="#">boton 2</div>
    <!-- ventanas modales ojala me ayuden  a usar un solo modal con una sola funcion se los agradeceria mucho -->
        <div id="miModal" class="modal">
         <div id="flex" class="flex">
           <div class="contenido-modal">
             <div class="modal-header flex">
               <h2></h2>
               <span id="close" class="close">&times</span></div>
                <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered" data-setud="{}" controls="" controlslist="nodownload"></video>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="miModal1" class="modal">
                    <div id="flex1" class="flex">
                        <div class="contenido-modal">
                            <div class="modal-header flex">
                                <h2></h2>
                                <span id="close1" class="close">&times;</span>
                            </div>
                            <video id="fm-video1" class="video-js vjs-16-9 vjs-big-play-centered" data-setup="{}" controls="" controlslist="nodownload"></video>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: La función videojs ¿qué hace? ¿De dónde sale? ¿Devuelve algún objeto? Si es de alguna librería o SDK probablemente tenga los métodos para cambiar la fuente del vídeo y deberías usarlos, llamando métodos nativos tal vez no es compatible. Lo del modal para saber porque abre o no habría que saber si usas otra librería para abrirlo porque tal vez cambiando la clase del modal no baste.

Comment: Si la verdad es de una librería que descargué para facilitarme la edición del entorno del video, pero probé usando el nativo y es igual a diferencia que no reconoce el video dice "su navegador no es compatible" (que a principio si funciona, antes de usar un solo modal para varios contenidos), y también sigue igual lo del modal y no no estoy usando librerias para el modal de hecho no he probado tratar de cambiar la clase de modal1 a modal2 porque no le veía sentido voy a probar a ver que tal, si me dieras alguna idea o sugerencia estoy dispuesto a probar todo y te agradezco mucho el apoyo.

Comment: Ah también, a lo de usar varios modales para varios contenidos ya lo he probado, de hecho fue lo primero que hice, pero luego me di cuenta que mi pagina cargaba mas lento de lo que carga con el codigo actual y pensé que debería haber una manera de hacer en su totalidad funcional, ya te podras imaginar lo que hay debajo de "/* Logistica, apertura y cierre con animacion de la ventana modal */" todo eso pero por x12 e igual pasa con el contenido de miModal x12 y así funciona bien pero carga un poco lento.